# Como fazer um select e um "Sub Select" de forma mais rápida (EM PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, select

Estou enfrentando problemas com query para contagem de registros.
Tenho uma tabela de clientes (separada por titulares e familiares).
E preciso contar os registros por status, porém o status do familiar vai ser o mesmo do titular.

**Faço da seguinte forma (estou usando PDO):**

```
//todos os titulares inativos
try{
    $titulares_i = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM clientes WHERE status != :status && registro_empresa = :registro && titular = :titular && cancelado = :cancelado"); 
    $titulares_i->bindValue(':status', 'ativo');
    $titulares_i->bindValue(':registro', '$_COOKIE['registro']');
    $titulares_i->bindValue(':titular', 's');
    $titulares_i->bindValue(':cancelado', '');
    $titulares_i->execute();
    $titulares_i_row = $titulares_i->rowCount();

}catch(PDOExeception $e){
    print $e->getMessage();
}//todos os titulares inativos
```

A quantidade de titulares eu ja tenho no **RowCount**, para **contar os dependentes** estou **criando um laço** com os *titulares*.

```
$contagem_dependentes = 0;
//Laço para trazer os familiares dos titulares inativos
while ($tit_i_arr = $tit_i->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {


        //todos os dependentes ativos (funcionários + dependentes)
    try{
        $dep_i = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM clientes WHERE registro_empresa = :registro && titular = :titular && id_titular = :id"); 
        $dep_i->bindValue(':registro', $cookie_adm);
        $dep_i->bindValue(':titular', '');
        $dep_i->bindValue(':num_card', $id_titular);
        $dep_i->execute();
        $dep_i_row = $dep_i->rowCount();

    }catch(PDOExeception $e){
        print $e->getMessage();
    }//todos os dependentes ativos (funcionários + dependentes) 

 $contagem_dependentes += $dep_i_row;

}//Laço para trazer os dependentes dos titulares inativos
```

Sei que tem praticas bem melhores, mas não conheço todo o funcionamento do SQL, estou estudando sobre.

Parecer bobo, pois claramente seria mais fácil fazer apenas 2 selects, porém como o status do familiar varia de acordo com o do titular,foi necessário selecionar por exemplo os titulares ativos e seus dependentes (então todos entram como ativos)

devido os milhares de registros, leva alguns minutos pra carregar, chegando a dar timeout normalmente..

Pela lógica, imaginei algo nesse sentido:

```
$parametros = $pdo->prepare("
SELECT id FROM clientes WHERE condicoes_aqui,
 lool_em_sql{
     SELECT id FROM clientes WHERE id_titular = id_titular_acima 
 }
  
");
```

**Porém não tenho noção de como fazer algo assim, nem se é possível, pesquisei bastante, porém só acho exemplos em outros padrões e confusos, que não se aplicam ao meu caso, ficaria super grato se alguém me desse uma luz.**

Obrigado!!!

Answer (score 1):

Caso você queira fazer sub selects ou selects onde tem alta complexidade da query talvez seja melhor você criar uma query manual dado que muitos frameworks eles não fazem selects complexos e apenas aninham selects consecutivos e depois colocam tudo dentro de arrays e te retorna o valor.

Por exemplo uma query que seria:

```
select * from table inner join table2 on table.id = table2.table_id where table.field = (select field from table where field = 'condition'
```

No seu caso eu vejo que aparentemente tu ta usando o objeto PDO puro do PHP, logo tu pode facilmente fazer uma raw query com ele conforme o próprio exemplo da docuemntação, [você pode encontrar exemplos clicando aqui.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)